# Pythonic way of zeroing numpy array axis

Tags: python, numpy

Bit annoyed I haven't been able to get this myself, so here goes.

Say I have a 2 dimensional numpy array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I am in a situation where I want to zero a column in this array, but maintain the original array. I can do this by

```
b = a.copy()
b[:,1] = 0
```

to get

```
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 9]])
```

or if I want to zero a series of columns, I can do

```
b = a.copy()
b[:,[0,3]] = 0
```

to get

```
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```

The b array will only be used one and then discarded.

Is there any more pythonic way of doing this that can be done as a one liner? I only want the zero valued b array to pass a plotting routine, after which is not needed. Essentially, I don't want to have an extra two lines before calling my plotting function - if I can do it as I call my routine it be much cleaner. For example

```
plotting_func(<numpy_magic_here>)
```

instead of

```
b = a.copy()
b[:,1] = 0
plotting_func(b)
```

only for b to never be used again

Comment: I can think of one-liners but not necessarily simpler and more readable...

Comment: Why do you want to create a copy of `a` with zeroed axes? Is it possible to change your plotting function so that you only pass the axes you care about (i.e. the ones you are not trying to zero)? Then you can do it with simple slicing in the function call.

Comment: Can't you just pass `a[:,[columns that are not zero]]` to the plotting function?

Comment: I have fitted a model to some data using emcee, giving me a large array where each row is an accepted sample of parameter values. When plotting my model over the data, I want to see a particular component of the model. I can doing by setting the normalization (say the second column of the array) of the second component to zero. I am hoping to do it this way so only maintain a single function without any extra logic.

Comment: Write a helper function that wraps your copy code.  Contrived one liners are not `pythonic`; they are `perlonic`.  :)

Comment: And I really don't like being `perlonic`. Was hoping there was some `numpy` indexing magic I didn't know about that also looked pretty :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set certain columns as zeros, you can use `np.in1d` alongwith `np.arange` to create a mask of invalid elements, which when multiplied with the input array would set the invalid columns as zeros using `NumPy broadcasting`. Thus, we would have an one-liner implementation, like so -

```
a*~np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[1]),cols_to_be_reset)
```

Alternatively, one can use `np.where` to choose instead of multiplying, like so -

```
np.where(np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[1]),cols_to_be_reset),0,a)
```

Please note that this is not meant for performance, but just as a one-liner.

Sample run -

```
In [546]: a
Out[546]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [547]: a*~np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[1]),1)
Out[547]: 
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 9]])

In [548]: a*~np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[1]),[0,2])
Out[548]: 
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```

Comment: Great - thanks for that! Looks as good as it can get judging from some of the other comments. Answer accepted.